# Bluetooth server with Python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, bluetooth

Python 3.3 came with native support for bluetooth sockets. Unfortunately, it's not too well documented yet (there is only one mention of it in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/socket.html?highlight=af_bluetooth)).

Googling it there is [a blog post](http://bitsofpy.blogspot.com.ar/2012/09/bluetooth-with-python-33.html) about implementing a client, but I couldn't find anything about creating a server.

More specifically, how to set the user-friendly name and advertise the service.

So, something like

```
import socket

serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH,
                             socket.SOCK_STREAM,
                             socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)
serverSocket.setTimeout(1)
serverSocket.bind(("", 1))
serverSocket.listen(1)

something.advertise_service(something something)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like they basically integrated pybluez.  Take a look at those examples: https://code.google.com/p/pybluez/source/browse/trunk/examples/simple/rfcomm-server.py

Comment: 'advertise_service' doesn't exist in the socket module nor in the server socket, and searching 'advert' in the python's source code finds only three unrelated comments.

Comment: I came across the same problem. I could make a simple server, but couldn't carryout tasks such as advertise services. You can see code for a client-server application here, if you are interested: http://kevindoran1.blogspot.co.nz/2013/04/bluetooth-programming-with-python-3.html

Comment: @TJD, PyBluez was copied from PyAffix which was in turn copied from python2.2.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Bad news*:
Python doesn't appear to support what you want to do out of the box. (At least not in [socketmodule.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/84cef4f1999a/Modules/socketmodule.c#l1)).

Most of the python/bluetooth users I've seen use [`pybluez`](https://code.google.com/p/pybluez/) although it hasn't been updated since 2009.

*Good news*:
I went through their source (for Linux connections), and found the relevant bits for advertising services. Most of the code is essentially copy-pasted from the python 2.2 version of `socketmodule.c`.

`pybluez` does define some additional functionality for a `socket` object to implement all those bluetooth goodies. It doesn't get too low-level, and instead depends on [`BlueZ`](http://www.bluez.org/) for that. From what I can tell, it basically takes python objects and creates the data structures expected by `BlueZ` and just calls that.
If you don't want to/can't use `pybluez`, you'll have to somehow implement this missing functionality. I think you may be able to do it with c-types. The relevant parts for advertising the service are in  [btmodule.c](https://code.google.com/p/pybluez/source/browse/trunk/bluez/btmodule.c), lines 2562-2642.

There is a python-3 branch in the source for `pybluez`, although I don't know if it works or not.

If you do decide to use `pybluez`, an example taken from [their source](https://github.com/karulis/pybluez/blob/master/examples/simple/rfcomm-server.py)

```
server_sock=BluetoothSocket( RFCOMM )
server_sock.bind(("",PORT_ANY))
server_sock.listen(1)

port = server_sock.getsockname()[1]

uuid = "94f39d29-7d6d-437d-973b-fba39e49d4ee"

advertise_service(server_sock, "SampleServer",
                  service_id = uuid,
                  service_classes = [ uuid, SERIAL_PORT_CLASS ],
                  profiles = [ SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE ], 
                  )
```

As google code is closing, the code can also be found on github [here](https://github.com/karulis/pybluez/).

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll end using the pc as slave since I needed to use py3.