# Using Bluetooth In Python

Tags: python, bluetooth

What i'm trying to do is control a motor via Bluetooth through a raspberry pi (with a Bluetooth dongle). So iv reached a stage in this where I have a client mobile device that can send text to the Bluetooth server end that python is running but I was wondering if there was any way for this end to send back text and if so what is the code for it in Python?

Thanks for any help you might be able to give.

Comment: Are you looking for "how to communicate via bluetooth with Python?". If the tutorials do not work: Do you need more tutorials? What motor do you use? Which tutorials do not work? What you are trying to do sounds great, keep up with it and if you have a solution, post it here!

Comment: Hi, that is exactly what I am trying to do but I cant really find any tutorials that show how to use an Android app as a clent then connect to the pi as a Bluetooth server.

Comment: These are two different questions. 1. How do I create an android app and a server. 2. How do I use Python with bluetooth. Choose one of them and reformulate the question. That gives you a higher chance of not confusing readers. ALso have a look at the sidebar on the right. Maybe there is something for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828916/bluetooth-server-with-python-3-3?rq=1