# Send binary data through bluetooth in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth

I am working in a project where I need to send/read data to/from a RFID reader through bluetooth in Ubuntu.

I am able to connect to the reader using `rfcomm connect`, but now I need to send/receive binary data to/from the reader through bluetooth. Looking for information I did not found the way to do it in Ubuntu. I found how to send an entire file using minicom, but that is not what I need, since I need to send/receive binary data from C/C++/Python.

Does somebody knows how to send/receive binary data through bluetooth?

Answer (score 2):

Since Python is an option, check out the [PyBluez](https://code.google.com/p/pybluez/) or [PyOBEX](https://bitbucket.org/dboddie/pyobex/) Python modules. Both allow you to transfer any type of data via Bluetooth and are well documented. PyOBEX only works if your client supports the OBEX protocol.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, PyBluez seems to be a good option. Now I'm having troubles with it to get bidirectional communication. It is very easy to get unidirectional direction, but as I need to communicate with an RFID reader I need to send commands and also receive results. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: @tonytr , for bidirectional communication you will have to implement some sort of listener that, after having established a connection, listens on some port for incoming packets from the RFID reader. You should look into the example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828916/bluetooth-server-with-python-3-3) for opening a port and listening. Then you should call something like socket.recv() as per the [API](http://pybluez.googlecode.com/svn/www/docs-0.7/public/bluetooth.BluetoothSocket-class.html). Don't forget to disconnect and close the socket when you're done.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @balt, finally I managed to communicate perfectly with the reader. Below I post how I did it. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Answering to my own question, the problem was that I implemented an obsolete communications protocol for my RFID reader, and it just responds when it "understand" the message received. It means, a message encoded with the obsolete protocol has no response, and the program seems to be blocked, but just because it has no response.

As it would be useful for somebody, the piece of code for bidirectional communication via Bluetooth with a CAEN RFID Reader using PyBluez I used is:

```
uuid = "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
addr = "00:12:F3:20:D7:E7"
service_matches = find_service( uuid = uuid, address = addr )

if len(service_matches) == 0:
     print("couldn't find the SampleServer service =(")
     sys.exit(0)

first_match = service_matches[0]
port = first_match["port"]
host = first_match["host"]

sock=BluetoothSocket( RFCOMM )
sock.connect((host, port))

string_set_protocol = "\x80\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x53\x58\x00\x1C\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x01\x00\x74\x00\x00\x00\x0A\x00\x54\x00\x00\x00\x03"

sock.send(string_set_protocol)
received_str = sock.recv(1024)
received_binary = ":".join("{:02x}".format(ord(c)) for c in received_str) #Print each byte in hexadecimal separated by ":"
print(received_binary)
```

And it worked perfectly